# Sparql dbpedia search article by containing word

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I've created sparql query for searching person and article

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
SELECT ?name ?person ?description 
WHERE {
?person rdf:type dbo:Person.
?person foaf:name ?name .
?person rdfs:comment ?description .
FILTER (regex(?description, 'morgan freeman' ,'i')) .
FILTER (lang(?description) = 'in')
} 
ORDER BY ?name
```

and its working when searching **morgan freeman**

but not working when searching article **God Created All Things** or **Birth of Jesus**

how to search acticle on dbpedia with sparql query?

Comment: Are you aware that your query restricts the search to persons (`?dbo:Person`)?

Comment: in addition to the restriction to the type `dbo:Person`: the data is there but the public DBpedia endpoint backed by Virtuoso makes use of the Virtuoso anytime feature, i.e. it returns as many result as possible found in the configured time. You an increase the time at least in the DBpedia web UI, but in the end it's not unlikely that the query can timeout given that it scans all the text with an expensive regex. the better way would be to use the fulltext index based search via `bif:contains`. Like `?description bif:contains '"morgan freeman"'`